# What is the linux equivalent for Windows tasklist memory usage?

Tags: linux, windows

In Tasklist, there'a column Memory usage. What is the equivalent in Linux parlance? RSS, VSZ, SIZE?

Comment: RES + SHR or %MEM

Comment: @Eddy_Em:  Please put it as an answer so I can mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

```
%MEM
```

This will display the percentage of memory that the process is currently using